# slow table column and row highlighter

Tags: jquery

i have 2 tables side by side (**#table-desc-data** and **#compare-table-data**), when the cursor is hovered over **#compare-table-data** the entire row and column in **#compare-table-data** is highlighted and the matching row in **#table-desc-data** is supposed to be too.

my code to highlight kind of works, but sluggish on a big tables, and sometimes doesn't highlight the whole row. any ideas? ([JSFIDDLE][1] - removed.)

```
 //code to highlight columns and rows
        $("#compare-table-data td").hover(function () {
            $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').
            add($(this).parent()).addClass('compare-hover');
            var idx = $(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex + 1;
            $('#table-desc-data').find('tr:nth-child(' + idx + ')').find('td').addClass('compare-hover');
        },

        function () {
            $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').
            add($(this).parent()).removeClass('compare-hover');
            $('#table-desc-data').find('td').removeClass('compare-hover');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want better performances use IDs in a structure like this:

```
| cell_1_1 | cell_1_2 |
| cell_2_1 | cell_2_2 |
```

So when for example you want to highlight the first column you can use jQuery selector like:

```
$('td[id^=cell_1_]')
```

The IDs are also indexed by the browser, and are faster

Answer (score 0):

For a fix to your code to get every row to highlight

add to hover enter function:

```
$(this).parent().find('td').addClass('compare-hover');
```

add to hover leave function:

```
$(this).parent().find('td').removeClass('compare-hover');
```

This will no effect the sluggishness though. But will get your rows to hightlight.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `tr:hover` CSS to highlight a row. To highlight a column, you can add a class to the corresponding `col`.

Example html:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col></col>
        <col></col>
        <col></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>C2</td>
        <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Example css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}

col.hovered {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Example jQuery:

```
$('td').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    var i = $(this).parent().children().index( this );
    $('col').removeClass('hovered');
    $('col:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').addClass('hovered');
} );

$('td').on( 'mouseleave', function() {
    $('col').removeClass('hovered');
} );
```

[A jsFiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sumurai8/uzkpu/)

Edit: I think a css selector `tr:hover` would be faster than any javascript solution - and more reliable. By attaching a class to a `col` instead of "every td in a certain column" you save yourself looping through all cells in a certain column. This will instead be done by the CSS engine of the browser. It is much easier to remove this 'hover-class' too, because you just need to remove the class from all `col` elements and reapply it to the right col (a trivial task), rather than looping through all td's to remove the class, then reapply it by looping through all td's again. For both solutions, I have no performance data to back it up though.

Edit 2: To add a class to a second table too, it'll get somewhat messy fast. The jQuery part would be something like this. The changes you need to make to the CSS should be obvious:

```
$('td').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    var coli = $(this).parent().children().index( this );
    var rowi = $(this).parent().parent().index( $(this).parent() );
    $('col').removeClass('hovered');
    $('col:nth-child('+(coli+1)+')').addClass('hovered');
    //Do the same trick for rows in 'the other table'
    $('#table2 tr').removeClass('hovered');
    $('#table2 tr:nth-child('+(rowi+1)+')').addClass('hovered');
} );

$('td').on( 'mouseleave', function() {
    $('col').removeClass('hovered');
    $('#table2 tr').removeClass('hovered');
} );
```

Comment: i have 2 tables tho. and want the 2nd tables highlighted row to also highlight the same row on table 1

Comment: I've added some extra jQuery to my answer, although I am somewhat confused why you want to highlight a row of a table that isn't visible. I have not tested that last bit, and it might require a `<tbody>` around the rows.